# How to reload appsettings.json at runtime each time it changes in .NET core 1.1 console application?

Tags: runtime, .net-core, configuration-files

I attempted to reproduce the method described in [this great article by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/reloading-strongly-typed-options-in-asp-net-core-1-1-0/). However, I am unable to get this running in a .NET core 1.1 console application. When the `appsettings.json` file is changed and saved, the changes are not reflected in the application without restarting it.

There are multiple files involved, so I created the smallest example I could come up [on github](https://github.com/rchampag/dotnetcore/tree/master/RuntimeReloadExample). I also provided details in the README.MD file on github.

Any help in resolving this would be most appreciated. Please keep in mind I am new to .NET core, and not an experienced developer. And this is my first question on stackoverflow... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't needed to do this but have you compared it to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#ioptionssnapshot), might shed some light.

Comment: Thanks for pointing there @Matt. Like the original article I cited, the doc also uses an ASP.NET app, as opposed to a console app. The initial app wiring is a little different in a console app, and I suspect this somehow causes different behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key thing to understand is *scope*.

There are three scopes in ASP.NET Core - transient, scoped, and singleton. `IOptionsSnapshot` is configured as a *scoped* service.

In ASP.NET Core, a scope is started for every request, so every request, you would get a new instance of `IOptionsSnapshot`, with updated configuration values.

In the example you provided, you are creating an `IServiceProvider`, and are fetching an instance of `IMyService` directly from the top level provider:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
Startup startup = new Startup();
startup.ConfigureServices(services);
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


while (true)
{
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
    var reply = service.DoSomething();

    Console.WriteLine(reply);
}
```

Essentially, you're always using the same scope for every request to the service provider, so you're always getting the same instance of `IOptionsSnapshot`. Effectively, if you never create a new scope, all of your scoped services become singletons!

The way to fix this is to create a new scope each time you fetch the service:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
Startup startup = new Startup();
startup.ConfigureServices(services);
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


while (true)
{
    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
        var reply = service.DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine(reply);
    }
}
```

This also becomes important if you're doing things like creating an EF Core `DbContext` outside the context of a request in ASP.NET Core app (or in a console app). Always create a new scope before accessing services from the service provider!

P.S. I've created a pull request to fix your sample :)

Comment: I stand educated! Many thanks for the fix, but more importantly for the detailed explanation of my newbie mistake. I hope others benefit from this too! The pull request has been merged, and the README.MD changed accordingly.